# using a library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I was hoping if someone could point me in the right direction for implementing the library [Lobster Picker](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/Lobsterpicker) in my android studio project.

I have been looking at different sites on how to implement, but all ask for link to a .jar file (github only has access to src). I'm a little confused as to where I add`compile 'com.larswerkman:lobsterpicker:1.0.1'`. I tried in a couple different gradle files, but it just broke the build.

Could someone help me?

Comment: do you add your jar file in libs folder?

Comment: Look at this file... See the compile line there? https://github.com/LarsWerkman/Lobsterpicker/blob/master/library/build.gradle

Comment: Please post your app build.gradle file. Or you can use a jar file instead of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the `build.gradle(Module:app)`, add the reference inside dependencies, like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.larswerkman:lobsterpicker:1.0.1'
}
```

Make sure your internet connection is working fine, otherwise will receive the error, `Project app: apk dependencies can only be jars.`

Comment: Thank you very much ... spent way to much time trying to do that